# How to calculate cycle time in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi

I' m trying to calculate the difference between two dates. Here is an example of my data:

```
id  operation   date    team
333 A   13/08/21    A
454 C   13/08/21    A
433 F   15/08/21    A
333 C   14/08/21    A
333 D   15/08/21    A
454 A   12/08/21    A
766 A   17/08/21    B
766 D   19/08/21    B
454 B   15/08/21    A
333 B   13/08/21    A
```

I want to calculate the average time between operation from all ids from one team.
I need to be able to filter this by operations and team.

Example: average time between operations A & C from team A.

Comment: As long as you are showing an *example image* instead of the *example data* no one can help you!

Comment: sorry, is this better?

Comment: Nope: Access Denied.

Comment: i changed the acess conditions, i cant use real data as it is against company rules

Comment: You should post exactly what final result you expect. By just reading your text I can come up with several different interpretations.